# IntelliJ cannot visualize Database

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a database I connect to using the IntelliJ Built in tool, and it connects properly to the test database and displays it, however, it doesn't display the tables with another database. I then tried connecting with the open source tool SQL Workbench, with the same information and it does properly connect to the database and displays the tables.

*test database:*

[image: test database]

*other database:*

[image: other database]

*other database in SQL Workbench:*

[image: other database in SQL Workbench]

When I click "Test Connection" In IntelliJ it connects properly for both the test and the other database, however one isn't actually displaying the tables.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong:

In the Database configuration file if you go to "Schemas & Tables" you can tick and untick what to show.

While I had never unticked anything, ticking the proper schema and adding it allowed me to visualize my database properly.

[image: Ticking schema on]